# SQL Select count of repeated dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select count of repeated dates and output its numbers

```
$user_curr_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM table_name WHERE user_ids = $user_curr_id";
```

I have no idea how to do it.

```
2014-07-23,2014-07-23,2014-07-23 => 3
2014-07-24,2014-07-24 =>2
2014-07-25 => 1
```

and get `$result = 3,2,1`

Comment: I'm expecting a `group by` answer plus a warning about sqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking after the GROUP BY clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT datum, COUNT(datum) as cnt
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE user_ids = $user_curr_id 
        GROUP BY datum
        ORDER BY COUNT(datum) DESC;";
```

if your column `datum` is of the data type `DATE`.

**Note**

As already mentioned you're vulnerable to sql injection. You should use a parameterized prepared statement and bind your input value to this parameter like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT datum, COUNT(datum) cnt
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE user_ids = ? 
        GROUP BY datum
        ORDER BY COUNT(datum) DESC;";

$result = array();
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    if ($stmt->bind_param('s', $user_curr_id)) {
        if($res = $stmt->execute()) {
            while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                $result[] = $row['cnt'];             // add the content of field cnt
            }
        }
    }
}
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Comment: how do I get the output $result = 3,2,1

Comment: how can you inject sessions?

Comment: @Grasper: First: never trust any input. Second: `implode(',', $results);` should give the result you need.

Comment: It's good practice to use prepared statements, if you can. But I don't know what's the content of your table. If you've got comma separated lists instead of DATE values in your column then I'll redraw my answer.

Comment: I have DATE values in the column

Comment: this is just breaking my site.